# How to fold to list using Linq (Aggregate)?

Tags: c#, f#

How do I convert the following F# (which converts an integer to string and replace some characters and reverse it, just an example. What I really need is how to do fold to `List` in C#) to C# using `Aggregate`?

```
// Convert an integer to string, replace some characters and reverse it
let convert (aInt:int) =
    let m = [ '0', 'O'; '1', 'l'; '8', 'B'; ....] |> Map.ofList
    string aInt |> Seq.fold (fun a e -> m.[e]::a) [] |> String.Concat
```

Will `m` be regenerated every time when the function `convert` is called in F#?

Comment: can you explain a little bit what is that code performing ?

Comment: Are you just trying to concat all of the strings in a list of strings/characters?

Comment: It converts an interger to string and replace some characters and reverse it.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 That sounds like a mechanism, not a requirement.  What are you *actually* trying to do?  It sounds like something that shouldn't be done through string manipulation at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly convert the code to C#, as many of the conversions aren't available in C# (at least not without referencing F#'s core libraries).

However, the following will provide equivalent results:

```
static string Convert(int value)
{
    // use a Dictionary instead of F# Map
    var m = new Dictionary<char, char>
    {
        {'0', 'O'},
        {'1', '1'},
        {'8', 'B'}
    };

    // Convert to IEnumerable<char> directly from dictionary
    var valStrs = value.ToString().Select(c => m[c]);

    // Build results from characters
    return new String(valStrs.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Note that you can do this with aggregate, but you'd end up doing something to mutate the aggregation value, so it still behaves differently than F#.  This mutated value could be a `List<T>` (as below), a `StringBuilder`, or anything else you want to aggregate.  I used a `List<T>` as this works with any type (not just string/char values), since I suspect this is likely to understand how to convert from a fold to aggregate, not this specific problem at hand:

```
static string Convert(int value)
{
    var m = new Dictionary<char, char>
    {
        {'0', 'O'},
        {'1', '1'},
        {'8', 'B'}
    };

    var valStrs = value
        .ToString()
        .Reverse()
        .Select(c => m[c])
        .Aggregate(new List<char>(), (list, val) => { list.Add(val); return list;});
    return new String(valStrs.ToArray());
}
```

---

> Will m be regenerated every time when the function convert is called in F#?

No.  You can see that from the following in FSI:

```
let convert (aInt:int) =
    let m = 
        printfn "m"
        [ '0', 'O'; '1', 'l'; '8', 'B'] |> Map.ofList
    string aInt |> Seq.fold (fun a e -> m.[e]::a) [] |> String.Concat
```

Calling `convert 8811;;` in FSI will output:

```
m
val it : string = "llBB"
```